# Cannot access property value on listbox item

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox with multiple selection activated and i am trying to read the different selected values

I have tried many snippets, here are the latest two :

```
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count
     MsgBox(ListBox1.Items((ListBox1.SelectedIndices(i))).value)
 Next


 For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count
     MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedItems(i).value)
 Next
```

For some reason with any approach i choose i can't read any item's value

My listbox is data bound, so i found out on a forum that making it public might fix the issue but it did not

I am hesitating as even Intellisense doesn't show much info, all i get is :

```
Equals
GetHashCode
GeType
ReferenceEquals
ToString
```

Any ideas where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: What kind of items are in the listbox? (a string, integer, an data table, a class object)?

Comment: they are all strings coming from DB and i am using data bindings (in flyout menu) to populate the listbox automatically on form load

Comment: Can you give more detail on the data binding sources.  Even better, show me the code that binds the listbox to the data source.  (Does the data source for listbox1 only have a single column?)

Comment: i am basically using the GUI for doing that (attached an img) and then in the form_load event, i only have : `Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.FillBy1(Me.SetupDataSet.Employee)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using the Data GUI tools in VB.  That said, I think what you are looking for is this:

```
For Each dvRow As DataRowView In Me.Listbox1.SelectedItems
  MessageBox.Show(dvRow("Id").ToString)
Next
```

If you were interested in the Last Name field, change "Id" to "Last Name".

Also, I used `MessageBox.Show` instead of `MsgBox`.   `MsgBox` is a leftover from VB6.

Comment: worked like a charm! i actually tried this before but without the `AS DataRowView` part and it made the difference i was so close :D thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you use a databound `ListBox`, the items aren't `ListBoxItem` objects (which you would expect to have `Text` and `Value` properties).  Rather they are the type from the data source.  The `Items` collection (and its variations, such as `SelectedItems`) is defined as a collection of objects, and the runtime type is obtained from the data source.  Have you tried something like this?

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count
    MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedItems(i).ToString())
Next
```

In the comments, you indicated that the data source is a DB object containing `String` objects.  If you have a collection of classes, such as `Person`, you can get it this way:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count
    MsgBox(DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItems(i), Person).FirstName)
Next
```

You should also get the same results with a `For Each`, as long as the selected items collection isn't changed while you are looping.

```
For Each p As Person in ListBox1.SelectedItems
    MsgBox(p.FirstName)
Next
```

**NOTE:  This is untested code, as I'm not in front of Visual Studio at the moment.**

**EDIT:**  I see from the screenshot that the `Value Member` is set to a property named `Id`.  If that is a `uniqueidentifier` column from the database, then the runtime type in the ListBox should be `Guid`.

Comment: i appreciate the help and mainly the explanation, the db is from an old software so no Guid though, i knew it was something with casting :D